# Host multiple web sites on port 80

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi, virtualhost

So I may be missing a bit of a fundamental understanding on what's going on here, but I cannot get this to work.  I have two django websites, and I want to be able to host them both on the same box, both on port 80.  Is there some magic to get this to work properly?  Here's what my sites-available/default file looks like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/proj/apache/django.wsgi
    AliasMatch ^/([^/]*\.css) /path/to/proj/static/
    Alias /media /path/to/proj/static/
    Alias /static/ /path/to/proj/static/

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/otherproj/apache/django.wsgi

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error2.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Obviously this doesn't work since navigating to the site hits the first one and it never goes to the second one.  So my question is, how do I set this up so I can host 2 web sites on port 80.  Perhaps I could do like localhost/site1 and localhost/site2 and figure it out that way, but no matter what I try I can't seem to get that to work.

I have played with the ServerName property, but I don't really understand how that can work, setting it doesn't seem to change that hitting the ip of that machine only shows the first website, and I don't know where using the ServerName affects anything.

Any suggestions, or let me know if I need to give more information.

Also note they both work if I change the second one to port 8080, but when doing that I can't seem to put a domain name on top of myip:8080.

Comment: How is it supposed to know which site to serve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is anything to explain here. You just need to actually *specify* the name of each virtual domain.

Note:**NameVirtualHost is deprecated**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName site1.ltd
    WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/proj/apache/django.wsgi
    AliasMatch ^/([^/]*\.css) /path/to/proj/static/
    Alias /media /path/to/proj/static/
    Alias /static/ /path/to/proj/static/

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName site2.ltd
    WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/otherproj/apache/django.wsgi

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error2.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: So lets say my ip is 1.2.3.4, how would doing this allow me to access each site differently?

Comment: You would have to register both site1.ltd and site2.ltd as pointing to ip 1.2.3.4.  Then people who visit site2.ltd will be routed to your server and your server will know (via the HTTP request headers) to serve the second site to them only.

Comment: Ok, so once I point a domain name toward that address it will know which to resolve based on the domain name used, but if I go straight to the address it will only be the first one?  I suppose that makes sense, I'll see if it works (though it takes up to an hour to change where my domain name points)

Comment: Almost too easy, I didn't realize apache would know what domain was used to get there, I was trying to figure out a way to get it to work by only accessing the ip address, but this is much easier.  Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_headers (In particular, the Host header field.)